# Saving Rankings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I am planning on calculating regional and global rankings once everyday. There will be multiple rankings, each based on ratings or stats.

What would be the best way to save these player rankings? Will it be better to create a table for each individual stat with each row containing playerID, regional rank and global rank, or create a single ranking table with lots of columns? The second option will lead to some rows having empty columns because a player might not have that specific stat.

Also, what would be the most efficient way to save the daily rankings to be able to create a graph that will show a player's progress? If I decide not to create a graph, I will just delete the table(s) before creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Just create one table with a primary key on playerId and date and add a column for each stat. YOu can then easily analyze anything on that table.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create two tables:
1- Ranking table (player_id,date,rank_id,rank)
2- Ranking_type (rank_id,description)

It's basically the same as the previous answer, but you can add or remove ranking types without having to alter the ranking table, it depends on how dynamic your application is

Answer (score 0):

The question centers on how the data is going to be used and on performance requirements.

If you have a situation where almost all the players have almost all the stats and your application is using all the stats at the same time, then it is a no-brainer from the performance perspective.  You want to store them in a single table, so you don't incur the overhead of the extra "playerid" per stat, along with the joins required to bring the data together.

At the other extreme, if most of the stats are empty and the application is using only one stat at a time, then a single table with "playerid", "statid", "value" is a good approach.

The second approach, which is an example of an entity-attribute-value (EAV) model, is also very beneficial when you need to add in new statistics.  However, you want to recreate all the values once per day and you don't mention a historical requirement.  This benefit is not apparent in your case.

Your option of storing the separate values in separate tables is probably not the best approach, especially if all the statistics have the same representation (i.e. one number).  Proliferating tables is generally a bad idea.  The one exception has to do with access control.  If you have separate security requirements for each statistic, then storing them in separate tables may make security easier to implement.

Based on what you say, I would go with the denomalized, one-row per player with many stats approach.  You probably want to see what a player looks like, and the data is just there with no additional processing, unless you have lots and lots of players or lots and lots of stats.